# How can I select a tantalum capacitor for a 2 MHz DC/DC boost power supply?

Tags: capacitor, boost, tantalum

I am using the MAX8815AETB+T in a fixed 5 V configuration in a design.

The [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/MAX8815A-3130408.pdf) recommends using a Cout = 22 μF tantalum (output capacitor). The problem I am having is that the boost converter works with a 2 MHz PWM signal and I don't know what characteristics the capacitor must have.

I tried to look for the impedance vs frequency graph, but most of the capacitors do not have it and they only mention the DF factor.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to relate the dissipation factor (DF) with the resonant frequency of a capacitor?
2. What characteristics must the capacitor you select have to avoid problems?

Answer (score 2):

Be VERY careful with using tantalum capacitors on the output of a boost converter.  The ripple current into the output cap can cause the tantalum to ignite and burn a nice hole into your PCB.

If you do use a tantalum make sure it's a low ESR polymer tantalum.  You probably also want to put a ceramic capacitor (or capacitors) in parallel to lower the effective overall ESR and provide more effective capacitance at 2 MHz.  The bulk tantalum cap can better deal with the load transients while the ceramic can better deal with the switching ripple.

You can relate the dissipation factor to the ESR of the capacitor, but not the self-resonant frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that a lot of datasheets for parts like this were written before good high-κ MLCCs were as cheap as they are today. If the datasheet was written prior to about 2005 to 2010 or so, it's likely that tantalum capacitors were the only option for much more than 1 μF with a lower-than-aluminum ESR. Nowadays, you can easily get a 22 μF MLCC that would likely be much superior to the tantalum capacitors the datasheet writers had to settle for, for much less money than the tantalum capacitor costs--the price of tantalum capacitors has gone up, while that of ceramic ones has fallen. You may need to adjust the compensation network slightly to account for the lower ESR.

Ceramic capacitors' lower ESR means lower losses and less heating in the capacitor. Even if they *do* heat up, ceramic capacitors are not flammable, unlike tantalum ones, which are notoriously prone to bursting into flame.

Long story short, even if the datasheet recommends a tantalum capacitor, the state of capacitor technology has advanced, and you probably want to use an MLCC instead.

Comment: When I see 'tantalum recommended' I get somewhat suspicious especially as for this part, *ceramics* are recommended for the input devices. The data sheet clearly states that the output capacitor is a part of the loop compensation (ensure regulation loop stability in the datasheet) and that often means that the somewhat higher ESR of the tantalum is required for stability *particularly for P channel output drivers* which is apparently the case here.. Whether that is true here, I don't know but I would be cautious.

Comment: @PeterSmith Even if that is the case, I'd give serious thought to a ceramic cap with a series resistor to increase the ESR. Tantalums have unpleasant failure modes.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to maintain about 22uF under bias and have low impedance at the switching frequency.  There is sometimes concern with MLCCs due to having lower impedance than electrolytics, but the datasheet says that is desirable.  That leaves capacitance under DC bias, which can be an issue for MLCCs:

[image]

As you can see in this example taken from [Murata](https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/index.html?lcid=en-us), you will lose a lot of effective capacitance at 5v using an MLCC with a small package.  Definitely do not try to slap a 22uF 0603 MLCC on there and call it a day.

Looking through their database, all of their standard 22uF 1206 MLCCs have between 10-14uF of effective capacitance at 5V bias, so I'd use 2x 22uF 1206 MLCCs.  You could pick out specific models based on their effective capacitance, but even the worst case is very nearly the recommended value so it probably isn't necessary.